# Map from OSM with d3js is inverted

Tags: d3.js, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to draw an exported from OSM city bounds.

I used overpass to extract data ([data](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ecb810fc6ba640d9f7df848f169103f1)).

Then I used d3js to draw it. ([bl.ocks](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/3cf48a6d5f1e77ffbf117a89549b7835))

```
var projection = d3.geoMercator( )
    .center( [ geometry_center.latitude, geometry_center.longitude ] )
    .scale( width * 80 )
    .translate( [ width / 2, height / 2 ] );

var path = d3.geoPath( ).projection( projection );

var svg = d3.select( '.wrap' ).append( 'svg' )
            .attr( 'width', width )
            .attr( 'height', height );

d3.json( 'dnepr-city.json', function( data ) {
    var el = svg.append( 'path' )
        .attr( 'd', path( data.features[ 0 ] ) )
        .attr( 'fill', '#555' )
        .attr( 'stroke', '#000' );
} );
```

As you can see, instead of city bounds, filled with grey color, it draws a white city and grey background.

(SO doesn't allow me to paste more links, so here's image: i.imgur.com/Xytgz21.png)

If I scale down the map, it displays as big (I guess, its 1/4 of Earth) square with a little hole — the city.

i.imgur.com/HBx4nse.png

So my question is how to invert this polygon. Not only the filling, but the coordinates — next my step is to use animation, so I cant work with hole, I need it as just a polygon.

**Added:** d3.geoPath( ).bounds gives some absurd values: +/- 179000, so I guess it's an error in data, but github's visualizer and mapsharper.org both shows correct polygons. So maybe I just doing something wrong?

**Added:** After some time and playing with diffirent tools I've managed to make this work. I just edited map data in, simplified it to ~35% and then exported as geojson, and everything is working now. I didn't post this as an answer because this looks like some hack for me.

Comment: Please add the most relevant part of your code to your question.

Comment: I've posted [full version](https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/3cf48a6d5f1e77ffbf117a89549b7835) of code in my question? I dont know what else I can post.

Comment: Use code blocks for the most relevant part. The question should also help people in the future, but your links may not direct to the code at some time.